# Pull Columns based on row value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table X

```
ID      A       B       C        D
1       T       T       F        T
2       F       T       F        T
3       T       F       T        F
```

So if my input is 1 for ID, then I want all column names that have value T for row 1. In above case A,B,D  or If ID is 3 then A and C.

How could I list these columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this

```
SELECT Y
FROM Table1
UNPIVOT (X FOR Y IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])) U
WHERE [ID] = 1 AND X = 'T'
```

Returns

```
+---+
| Y |
+---+
| A |
| B |
| D |
+---+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a23f9/1)

Comment: All 3 are correct answers. I prefer this as this gives output on each row. It does take an effort to add in all the columns(Our table has 78 columns). Thank you Martin, for doing a demo on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use XQuery with powerful FLWOR Expression. And no matter how many columns contains a table;)

```
SELECT(
       SELECT *     
       FROM Table1 t
       WHERE ID = 1 
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
       ).query(
               'for $spec in ./*
                where $spec [contains(., "T")]           
                return fn:local-name($spec)'
                ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45243/3)

This decision returns the names of columns on each row

```
SELECT o.TCols.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') AS T 
FROM(SELECT(
            SELECT *     
            FROM Table1 t
            WHERE ID = 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).query('
                     for $spec in ./*
                     where $spec [contains(., "T")]           
                     return (
                             <TCols>
                               {fn:local-name($spec)}
                             </TCols>
                             )
                     ')) t(TCols) CROSS APPLY T.TCols.nodes('/TCols') o(TCols)
```

Results

```
+---+
| T |
+---+
| A |
| B |
| D |
+---+
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45243/7)

Comment: As Alexander states the columns don't matter. The only problem is its list all the columns in one row, one column separated by space. Thank you doing a demo on SQLFiddle.

Comment: Ok.The following solution will solve this problem. Answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

In case that you know the number and name of all columns, you may do the below

```
SELECT case A when 'T' then 'A' else '' end
  + case B when 'T' then ',B' else '' end
+ case C when 'T' then ',C' else '' end
+ case D when 'T' then ',D' else '' end
FROM
 Table1
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: But he wants all possible combinations and a single result e.g. `A,B,D` or `B,D` or `C` (so with comma). `@ID` and `@TVal` are also parameters. Apart from that your current sql will not work because the syntax is not correct.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that was a simple demonstration to provide a way before making sure it's working. Kindly see updated answer.